# Getting an error while converting string to DateTime

Tags: c#, datetime

I am trying to convert a string value into DateTime. It gives me an error as, specified string is not in correct format.

Here is the code,

```
DateTime myDate = DateTime.ParseExact("07-09-2013 01:14:14:1414", "yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss", System.Globalization.CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
string strDate = "07/09/2013 01:04:02:4";
Convert.ToDateTime(strDate); 
DateTime dt = DateTime.Parse(strDate);
```

Please help in converting the same.

Thanks

Comment: Never heard of this exception.

Comment: @TimSchmelter Oh stop it, you.

Comment: My answer won't work in your case? http://stackoverflow.com/a/17543140/447156

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your format seems to be incorrect. Should be:

```
"dd-MM-yyyy HH:mm:ss:ffff"
```

**Update.** If number of digits representing fractions of a second varies, than the best bet is

```
"dd-MM-yyyy HH:mm:ss:FFFFFFF"
```

Refer to [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8kb3ddd4.aspx) for other options for custom time and date formats.

Comment: Are you sure this works, guess for invariant the millisecond part needs a decimal point like `ss.ff`

Comment: 1414 suggests 4 characters, which will be 'ffff'. See http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8kb3ddd4.aspx

Comment: @Andrei This worked, with appended AM/PM. How can I remove AM/PM

Comment: @VijayBalkawade, there is no AM/PM in the original string, so it is not clear what you mean by `appended AM/PM`. However you always can add `tt` to the format to take those into account: `dd-MM-yyyy HH:mm:ss:ffff tt` should successfully parse `07-09-2013 01:14:14:1414 AM`.

Comment: @Andrei The output is 9/7/2013 1:14:14 AM. I want to remove the AM or PM.

Comment: @VijayBalkawade, how are you producing the output?

Comment: @Andrei DateTime myDate = DateTime.ParseExact("07-09-2013 01:14:14:1414", "dd-MM-yyyy HH:mm:ss:ffff",
                                       System.Globalization.CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);

Comment: @VijayBalkawade, this gives you a `DateTime` instance, not a string. I assume by `output` you mean a string, say `myDate.ToString()`? If this is the case, then use `myDate.ToString("dd-MM-yyyy HH:mm:ss:ffff")`. Otherwise it is not clear what do you mean by `output`. `DateTime` object itself does not define `AM/PM` tokens, this is just a representation feature.

Comment: @Andrei In the code I have provided in comment, it is DateTime object i.e. myDate. When I ran the code, it gave me value as  9/7/2013 1:14:14 AM. If I convert it again in string, it would be of no use.

Comment: @VijayBalkawade, and yet again, what does `it gave me value` mean? How are you using `myDate` (note that in the OP it is not used)? Or maybe you see this value in debug (which is actually a string representation)?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/33127/discussion-between-vijay-balkawade-and-andrei)

Comment: @Andrei Ohh I see. Let me check the implementation in actual code. Thanks a lot for your help :)

Comment: @Andrei it is partially working. The date in string format is provided at run time, so the miliseconds are changing. ffff works if there are 4 digits in input string. Otherwise it fails.

Answer (score 1):

Your format isn't correct:
"**07-09-2013** 01:14:14:1414"
"**yyyy-MM-dd** HH:mm:ss"

Atleast your date is the other way around, and the milliseconds is not specified.
Correct you format according to this: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8kb3ddd4.aspx

For the downvoter:
The correct format is specified by Andrei: `"dd-MM-yyyy HH:mm:ss:ffff"`

Comment: Yup, someone is downvoting you but you are right. However you should be more clear

Comment: Sigh indeed, I was trying to let the Vijay understand why it was wrong. The correct format is posted by Andrei.

Answer (score 1):

Try in your page_load event:

```
Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentUICulture = New System.Globalization.CultureInfo("tr-TR")
Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture = New System.Globalization.CultureInfo("tr-TR")
```

Comment: `Page_Load`? Why? And why do you force him to use `Turkish` culture. That's pointless.

Comment: Page_Load to see if his problem is culture specific. Turkish culture because as far as I can understand, he is trying to convert a date to a dd/MM/yyyy format.. I only suggested a quick test not an actual solution to the case itself hence the word "Try" in the beginning of my anwer.

Comment: surely you would put this into a comment then, because this field is retained for answers....

Comment: @Emin First of all, this could be a console application or a  winforms application too. You can't be sure about that. Second of all, OP used `InvariantCulture` in his code, so he wants to parse it _culture-independent_. There is no point to suggest him to use a specific culture.

Answer (score 1):

First, you mixed you years place

```
07-09-2013 is dd-MM-yyyy format
```

second, you need a :ffff after seconds

So the final line should be

```
DateTime myDate = DateTime.ParseExact("2013-07-09 01:14:14:1414", "yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss:ffff", System.Globalization.CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
```

Answer (score 1):

First of all, you should change your date format to `dd-MM-yyyy` because it fits with your date format.

Second of all, for miliseconds part, you can use `.` instead of `:`

```
DateTime myDate = DateTime.ParseExact("07-09-2013 01:14:14.1414", "dd-MM-yyyy HH:mm:ss.ffff", System.Globalization.CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
string strDate = "07/09/2013 01:04:02.4";
Convert.ToDateTime(strDate);
DateTime dt = DateTime.Parse(strDate);
```

Here a [**DEMO**](http://ideone.com/f1IGNy).

For more information, check [`Custom Date and Time Format Strings`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8kb3ddd4.aspx)